# React-native No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'

Tags: android, react-native

when I run my react-native v0.49 app (after installing one-signal plugin) I get the error

> AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>
> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

I saw some posts with the same error and their solution is to change in build.gradle the version from

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
```

to

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'
```

when I change it works but I don't want this solution since it limit the
Audience of users can use in the app I build.

so any other solution for this error?

Comment: No, it doesn't limit the audience. `targetSdkVersion` does that. All `compileSdkVersion` does is give you the capability of using the new API features of Android as well as all the previous features.

Comment: What libraries are you using?

Comment: what do u mean? I'm using react native v0.49 and installed facebooksd,branch io,onesignal,camera,qr code.